# How to reset an asyncio eventloop by a worker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, event-loop

I'm working with an `asyncio forever()` eventloop. Now I want to restart the loop (stop the loop and recreate a new loop) after a process or a signal or a change in a file, but I have some problems to do that:

---

Here are three simplified code snippets in which demonstrate some coroutine workers and a coroutine loop restarter:

---

*#1st try:*

```
import asyncio

async def coro_worker(proc):
    print(f'Worker: {proc} started.')
    while True:
        print(f'Worker: {proc} process.')
        await asyncio.sleep(proc)

async def reset_loop(loop):
    # Some process
    for i in range(5):  # Like a process.
        print(f'{i} counting for reset the eventloop.')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    main(loop)  # Expected close the current loop and start a new loop!

def main(previous_loop=None):
    offset = 0
    if previous_loop is not None:  # Trying for close the last loop if exist.
        offset = 1  # An offset to change the process name.
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            print('Cancel the tasks')  # Why it increase up?
            task.cancel()
            # task.clear()
            # task.close()
            # task.stop()

        print("Done cancelling tasks")
        asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()

    process = [1 + offset, 2 + offset]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [loop.create_task(coro_worker(proc)) for proc in process]
    futures.append(loop.create_task(reset_loop(loop)))

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('Tasks has been canceled')
        main()  # Recursively
    finally:
        print("Closing Loop")
        loop.close()
main()
```

Out[1]:

```
Worker: 1 started.
Worker: 1 process.
Worker: 2 started.
Worker: 2 process.
0 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 1 process.
1 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 2 process.
Worker: 1 process.
2 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 1 process.
3 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 2 process.
Worker: 1 process.
4 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 1 process.
Cancel the tasks
Cancel the tasks
Cancel the tasks
Done cancelling tasks
Closing Loop
Closing Loop
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task cancelling coro=<reset_loop() done, defined at reset_asycio.py:11> exception=RuntimeError('Cannot close a running event loop',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reset_asycio.py", line 40, in main
    loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 425, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reset_asycio.py", line 17, in reset_loop
    main(loop)  # Expected close the current loop and start a new loop!
  File "reset_asycio.py", line 48, in main
    loop.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 63, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 96, in close
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<reset_loop() running at reset_asycio.py:11>>
reset_asycio.py:51: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'reset_loop' was never awaited
  main()
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<coro_worker() running at reset_asycio.py:4>>
reset_asycio.py:51: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'coro_worker' was never awaited
  main()
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<coro_worker() running at reset_asycio.py:4>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<coro_worker() running at reset_asycio.py:8> wait_for=<Future cancelled>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<coro_worker() running at reset_asycio.py:8> wait_for=<Future cancelled>>
```

---

*#2nd try:*

```
.
.
.

def main(previous_loop=None):
    offset = 0
    if previous_loop is not None:  # Trying for close the last loop if exist.
        previous_loop.stop()
        previous_loop.close()
        offset = 1  # An offset to change the process name.

    process = [1 + offset, 2 + offset]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [loop.create_task(coro_worker(proc)) for proc in process]
    futures.append(loop.create_task(reset_loop(loop)))

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('Tasks has been canceled')
        main()  # Recursively
    finally:
        print("Closing Loop")
        loop.close()
main()
```

Out[2]:

```
Worker: 1 started.
Worker: 1 process.
Worker: 2 started.
Worker: 2 process.
0 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 1 process.
1 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 2 process.
Worker: 1 process.
2 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 1 process.
3 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 2 process.
Worker: 1 process.
4 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 1 process.
Closing Loop
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<reset_loop() done, defined at reset_asycio.py:9> exception=RuntimeError('Cannot close a running event loop',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reset_asycio.py", line 15, in reset_loop
    main(loop)  # Expected close the current loop and start new loop!
  File "reset_asycio.py", line 21, in main
    previous_loop.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 63, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 96, in close
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<coro_worker() done, defined at reset_asycio.py:3> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7efed846f138>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<coro_worker() done, defined at reset_asycio.py:3> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7efed846f048>()]>>
```

---

*#3rd try:*

```
.
.
.

def main(previous_loop=None):
    offset = 0
    if previous_loop is not None:  # Trying for close the last loop if exist.
        offset = 1  # An offset to change the process name.
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            print('Cancel the tasks')  # Why it increase up?
            task.cancel()

    process = [1 + offset, 2 + offset]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [loop.create_task(coro_worker(proc)) for proc in process]
    futures.append(loop.create_task(reset_loop(loop)))

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('Tasks has been canceled')
        main()  # Recursively
    finally:
        print("Closing Loop")
        loop.close()
main()
```

Out[3]:

```
Worker: 1 started.
Worker: 1 process.
Worker: 2 started.
Worker: 2 process.
0 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 1 process.
1 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 2 process.
Worker: 1 process.
2 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 1 process.
3 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 2 process.
Worker: 1 process.
4 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 1 process.
Cancel the tasks
Cancel the tasks
Cancel the tasks
Closing Loop
Worker: 2 started.
Worker: 2 process.
Worker: 3 started.
Worker: 3 process.
0 counting for reset the eventloop.
1 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 2 process.
2 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 3 process.
3 counting for reset the eventloop.
Worker: 2 process.
4 counting for reset the eventloop.
Cancel the tasks
Cancel the tasks
Cancel the tasks
Cancel the tasks
Cancel the tasks
Cancel the tasks
Closing Loop
Worker: 2 started.
Worker: 2 process.
Worker: 3 started.
Worker: 3 process.
.
.
.
```

---

#Problem:

- In the *#3rd try*, apparently I've done it, but `print('Cancel the tasks')` increases up after each restarting, what's the reason?!
- Is there a better approach to overcome this problem?

Forgive me for the long question I tried to simplify it!

---

[NOTE]:

- I'm not looking for the `asyncio.timeout()`
- I also tried with another thread in order to restart the eventloop with an unsuccessful result.
- I'm using *Python 3.6*

Comment: Why do you want to reset the event loop? That is an unusual idea.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this - i.e. what problem are you solving?

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm trying to implement an SNMP collector with the several configurations which stored in a file, I parse these configs, each config is given to the coroutine SNMP collector (like `coro_worker()` in question) in init loop (`loop.create_task()`). my SNMP collector (`coro_worker()`) has an indefinite loop. Problem is that when the config file changes, I can't stop this event loop (`run_forever()`) and recreate the coroutine SNMP collector with the new config.

Comment: This could be an XY problem. While you are focusing on how to reset the eventloop you should focus on how to properly end your task.

Comment: @KlausD. Is it necessary to ensure the end of the tasks to stop or close the event loop?

Comment: You are still asking the wrong question. You don't reset or stop the event loop except in very special cases (not yours). It usually ends when the program ends.

Comment: @KlausD. My collector is not a finishable program, it is an infinite service, but it needs to restart and recreate the tasks with a signal or changing in the config file. I looking for to a mercilessly stop tasks method. If there is any other idea I will appreciate that.

Comment: You can always stop the event loop with its `stop` method, then close it and start a new one. You can also cancel all your tasks and re-create them within the same event loop.

Comment: @user4815162342 In the `#2 try` snippet code on my question I did it (`stop` then `close`) but I encountered with the mentioned error in the `Out[2]` in my question. I also tried with `cancel` task in `#3 try` snippet code, but I think the tasks remain in the background.

Comment: Maybe you are overcomplicating things with the recursion and the stopping, etc. Take a look at [this code](https://pastebin.com/5p4dRxyc) - it monitors an external source (the file system) and, when a file is created, it just stops the loop. `main()` then has the code that cancels the tasks it has created, and replaces them with new ones. That looks like it should resolve your issue.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you, I'll check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recursive call to `main()` and the new event loop adds unnecessary complication. Here is a simpler prototype to play with - it monitors an external source (the file system) and, when a file is created, it just stops the loop. `main()` contains a loop that takes care of both (re-)creating and cancelling the tasks:

```
import os, asyncio, random

async def monitor():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        if os.path.exists('reset'):
            print('reset!')
            os.unlink('reset')
            loop.stop()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def work(workid):
    while True:
        t = random.random()
        print(workid, 'sleeping for', t)
        await asyncio.sleep(t)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(monitor())
    offset = 0
    while True:
        workers = []
        workers.append(loop.create_task(work(offset + 1)))
        workers.append(loop.create_task(work(offset + 2)))
        workers.append(loop.create_task(work(offset + 3)))
        loop.run_forever()
        for t in workers:
            t.cancel()
        offset += 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Another option would be to never even stop the event loop, but to simply trigger a reset event:

```
async def monitor(evt):
    while True:
        if os.path.exists('reset'):
            print('reset!')
            os.unlink('reset')
            evt.set()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

In this design `main()` can be a coroutine:

```
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    reset_evt = asyncio.Event()
    loop.create_task(monitor(reset_evt))
    offset = 0
    while True:
        workers = []
        workers.append(loop.create_task(work(offset + 1)))
        workers.append(loop.create_task(work(offset + 2)))
        workers.append(loop.create_task(work(offset + 3)))
        await reset_evt.wait()
        reset_evt.clear()
        for t in workers:
            t.cancel()
        offset += 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    # or asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Note that in both variants canceling the tasks is implemented by `await` raising a `CancelledError` exception. The task must not catch all exceptions using `try: ... except: ...` and, if it does so, needs to re-raise the exception.

Comment: Is the second section in your answer compatible with *Python 3.7*?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari The second section is written specifically for Python 3.7 in mind. It can also work in Python 3.5/3.6, just replace the `asyncio.run` line with the commented-out line below it.

Comment: Sometimes I encountered with this error in my workers (`work()`): `concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError` then the previous task runs with the new task after the change, simultaneously.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari What do you mean by "encountered the error"? Are you perhaps catching all exceptions? Raising a `CancelledError` is how asyncio terminates a task. If your code is catching that exception, it should immediately re-raise it.

Comment: My mean that I sometimes I confront with this error `concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError` in my `work()` method which contained with `try` and `exception`. in exception this error is shown, and previous task that I expected it remove remains with the new task with the new change.

Comment: I am trying with a worker which contained with an `exception asyncio.CanclledError:` that raised immediately, but also in the worker placed a `finally`, is it dangerous?

Comment: Problem fixed with a `raise` in `exception asyncio.CanclledError`. Thanks a lot. I'm going to edit your answer with this exception. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari The `raise` doesn't fit in the answer because that code doesn't catch exceptions in the first place. With your edit it catches `CancelledError` only to immediately re-raise it, which doesn't make sense and is unnecessary. (The code in the answer works correctly without the try/except/raise.) I've now added a paragraph that warns about accidentally catching `CancelledError`.